# Angular6 - How to initialize child component when parent is initialized?

Tags: angular, parent-child, angular6

pretty new to Angular6, maybe you can help me understand how to solve this.

I have a panel that has multiple tabs.
The panel is the parent component, and each tab is a different child component.
In one of the child components I have a subscription to a service to retrieve a list of users, manipulate the list and display it in the tab content.

Everything works, but now I added a mat-badge icon in the tab header, that shows a number. That number is given by the child component, as it's the array's length of the manipulated list.

When I subscribe from the parent to the child's manipulated list, to retrieve the numbers to show in the mat-badge, the issue is, when the panel is first open, the child that has the list still isn't initialized, until its tab is clicked, 
so the subscription I do from the parent doesn't work because it returns undefined.

There must be multiple solutions to this,
One should be a way to initialize a specific tab child, as soon as I open the main panel, so the parent can retrieve the data and put it in the tab label.

What lifecycle hook should I be using? 
Or would it be possible to just initialize a part of the child code when the parent panel is opened? and not everything?

Thank you

Comment: As I can see it, you can add and @output to the child or move the resources into an upper level, if you can edit your question and add how did you implemented it now it will be more helpful

Comment: I can't move it into the parent level, because each tab (each child component) has a different function and different subscriptions to retrieve data, so for most of them It s good that the subscriptions fire only when the child is initialized, but in this single case, as I need the child's data for the mat-badge in the tab label, I just need that piece of data from the child as soon as the parent is initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**your problem is in your architecture, in that case you should move the login into an upper level at your system or into a service if you will need it there.**

any way if you got to keep architecture as it is now, you can use ngClass as follow since with ngClass unlike ngIf the browser still drawing and initializing the component.

```
@Output() onChildInit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

and after your child component done the it process and the data is ready,

```
 this.onChildInit.emit(data);
```

at your parent component add:

```
<ChildComponent [ngClass]="showChild?'':'hidden'"(onChildInit)="DataIsHere($event)"></ChildComponent>
```

you should make sure that the child component is loaded and that there is no ngIf that preventing it from initializing.

you can read more about Angular Event emitters and @Output [in here](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)
and about angular life cycle [in here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: but would this solve my issue? from what I understand, in this case 
<ChildComponent (onChildInit)="DataIsHere($event)"></ChildComponent>

this part would just be initialized only when data is ready? but data won't be ready until I switch to the child's tab and fire the ngOnInit part in its component? 

what I need is the parent, being able to access to SOME data that is in the child component, BEFORE the child component is initialized, so somehow initialize that part of data as soon as the parent gets initialized as well

Comment: I editted my answer, look at the update in the <ChildComponent ...> tag

Comment: thank you, but as far as I can understand, this seems not to be the right way for me, you basically are emitting from the child when the data is ready, and based on that, you show or hide the <childComponent> in the html file of the parent, but this means that the child component has to be initialized, and what I need is the data from the child as soon as the parent is initialized! I thought there was maybe a lifecycle hook I could put in the child component, that makes that part of code initialize with the parent! if there is not such thing, then I should move everything in a service

Comment: yes, In your case I think that service is the way to go.
you can look at the life cycle hooks. 
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks